# Get list of friends who live in a specific area

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook has recently started allowing you to view the newsfeed of people in areas, for example for me I live in leeds and can see 'Leeds Area'.

How would I go about using the PHP SDK to populate a list of these user's ID's for an application? At the moment I'm manually typing these into my application and its becoming rather tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that Facebook user Id's can not be obtained unless a user gives permission of at least user_about_me or higher.

They protect the UserId's well and I know of no known way to acheive it otherwise.

Comment: I'm able to view a list of my own friends user id's, i was just wondering if it was some how possible to filter these by area. Like facebook does in its main website.